# Adding OrderBy clause to a named query

Tags: jpa

Is it possible to add an OrderBy clause in to JPA Named query at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Named queries are processed by the persistence provider when the EntityManagerFactory is created. You can't change/modify/append anything about a named query dynamically at runtime.

If you are using JPA 2.0 and you need a way to do high-performance dynamic queries at runtime, you should look into the Criteria API.

Comment: Although is it true that "You can't change/modify/append anything about a named query dynamically at runtime", this is not true for generated underlying SQL. For instance think about when you call a setMaxResults() or setFirstResult(): you are going to modify the actual query by adding some limit and offset clause. This is just to tell that there is no a strict dependency between a NamedQuery and a compiled query in dbms.

Answer (score 1):

From Java EE 5 Documentation : "**Is used to specify a named query in the Java Persistence query language, which is a static query expressed in metadata. Query names are scoped to the persistence unit**".

As it says, it is static & you can't change the query at runtime.
Rather use custom query or if ordering element is fixed then you can use annotation;

Field:

```
@OrderBy(value="nickname")
List<Person> friends;
```

Method:

```
@OrderBy("nickname ASC")
public List<Person> getFriends() {...};
```

Answer (score -2):

Even if you can't add order-by clause to your named query, you can provide a parametric orderBy. The following is a perfectly valid query:

```
SELECT u FROM User u ORDER BY :orderBy
```

And you are going to change ordering with something like:

```
query.setParameter("orderBy", "id");
```

Comment: I guess it depends on JPA driver you're working with. I'm sure I've successfully used this in the past